# Python Thread Info

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python program with 4 threads and I would like to get the cpu and memory usage for one of the threads. I have used os.getpid() and then use top -H -p to get the information on the parent pid. If os.getpid() returns 3000 then top -H -p gives info on pid's 3000, 3001, 3002, 3003, and 3004. I assume that each increment is the next thread but is this always the case? Is there a better way of getting this information for one thread?
I am running python 2.7 on linux.

Thanks

Comment: `os.getpid()` returns the PID of the _process_. New threads you create may or may not have the same PID as the main thread, depending on your platform, but if they have different PIDs, they will all be children, so you can just use `-ppid` to list them all, or you can use `ps` to enumerate the PIDs and then use the one(s) you want, or… whatever is appropriate.

Comment: As a side note, it sounds like you've got some CPU-bound code running in multiple threads. This is usually a bad idea, because the GIL will end up serializing them almost completely, and then adding overhead, so your 4-threaded program will run about 10-50% slower than a single-threaded version, instead of 4x faster. If you need parallelism in Python, you need processes, not threads.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for resurrecting an old question.
My solution to this problem on linux - 
In the python thread

- create a temp file
- get process PID
- scan /proc/PID/task to get task-pids
- save the wchar: value in each /proc/PID/task/task-pid/io
- write a random number of chars to a temp file (remember the number of chars you wrote)
- rescan the /proc/PID/task/task-pid/io files
- eliminate task-pids that dont have the right increase in wchar
- rinse and repeat as often as required to end up with 1 (or possibly 0) task-pid